# ADK blink tutorial: on board LED is always on

Tags: android, arduino, adk

I have a [Duemilanove](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001VK18HC) and [ADK](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=74&products_id=2149) and I followed [this](http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/) and with the exception of some SDK updates, I followed it exactly.

Problem: the onboard LED doesn't blink but is always on.

Issues:

- byte array is being successfully sent to the ADK from the phone, verified by monitoring serial port of arduino board
- High & low signal is being properly handled in the arduino code (same verification).
- the blink tutorial without the ADK blinks the on board LED properly.

So, what is wrong? Is it possible that the ADK board is always sending a HIGH signal to the on board LED and I need to use an 'external' LED for testing? A lot of the tutorials I've seen do this so could that be why?

Comment: I think the issue is that the LED does switch to off but the time between loops is so short that it is not observed. I'm not sure why the LED is continually sent the HIGH signal but I don't think it has to do with my code. If I add in a delay(500) for example, you can easily see the code working properly.

Comment: Where in the code do you have to add the `delay(500)`?

Comment: after the call to digitalWrite(PIN_13,LOW);

Answer (score 1):

Try to write a small blink program, just to check that everything is alright in your ADK board.

Comment: the blink program on the arduino board runs fine. I'll try with the ADK plugged in...

Comment: yeah, the simple blink program runs fine the the ADK board plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

The onboard Arduino LED is on initially. It looks like it is never being turned off.

In the [linked instructions](http://allaboutee.com/2011/12/31/arduino-adk-board-blink-an-led-with-your-phone-code-and-explanation/), under the section *How To Receive Data From The Android Device* , the first line of the `loop()` function is:

```
byte msg[0];
```

Then to receieve data in the call to `AndroidAccessory.read()` the value `sizeof(msg)` is used to determine how many bytes to read.

However, because `msg` was defined to be 0 bytes long, no bytes will be read, `len` will be zero and the LED will not be updated.

Instead, try changing the line to:

```
byte msg[1];
```

Comment: yeah, i noticed that last night, after I created this posting. Made the change but no change in the behaviour of the board/app. It looks like the message is being processed properly but without the turn off + sleep the LED stays on. I have a related post on electroics: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30307/understanding-what-is-suppose-to-happen-in-this-arduino-adk-example

Comment: What output do you get if you add `Serial.println("Turning LED on");` just before `digitalWrite(LED_PIN,HIGH);` and `Serial.println("Turning LED off");` just before `digitalWrite(LED_PIN,LOW);`?

Comment: I tried that, the print out correspond with the toggle of the button on the phone. From the printf debugging standpoint everything appers to be working the way it should. but it is not. that's why I am curious to know if maybe the board should sleep for sometime or not?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the shield you are using but it looks like it uses SPI for communication.  SPI uses pin 13 for the serial clock signal (SCK).  Given this I would expect the SCK signal may be interfering with you trying to control the LED.

I would suggest trying to wire an LED to a different digital pin such as pin 8 and update the Arduino sketch to use pin 8.  This would remove the possibility of conflict.